# javascript how to regex match and replace on hashtags but exclude the hashtag character

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following function:

```
function formattedTitle(posttitle,hreflink) {
  return `<a href='`+ hreflink +`'>` + posttitle.replace(/(^|\s)(#[-.\w]+)/gi, `$1</a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"$2"'>$2</a><a href='`+ hreflink + `'>`) + '</a>';
}
```

When I run

```
console.log(formattedTitle('This is #awesome news','google.com'));
```

It outputs:

```
<a href='google.com'>This is </a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"#awesome"'>#awesome</a><a href='google.com'> news</a>
```

```js
function formattedTitle(posttitle, hreflink) {
  return `<a href='` + hreflink + `'>` + posttitle.replace(/(^|\s)(#[-.\w]+)/gi, `$1</a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"$2"'>$2</a><a href='` + hreflink + `'>`) + '</a>';
}


console.log(formattedTitle('This is #awesome news', 'google.com'));
```

Notice how it includes the "#" in the $2 match. How can I exclude the hashtag character in the `hashtag:` attribute but keep it in between the href value?

So the output should look like:

```
<a href='google.com'>This is </a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"awesome"'>#awesome</a><a href='google.com'> news</a>
```

I have been able to get it to work by doing another replace on the entire thing to replace `'/search?q=hashtag:"#` with `'/search?q=hashtag:"` but I am wondering if it's possible without the second replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `#` outside of the captured 2nd group, so it isn't captured. When replacing, in the `href`, replace with just `$2` (so no hashtag). When replacing the *text inside* the `<a>`, replace with `#$2`, so that the hashtag gets added in the proper place:

```js
function formattedTitle(posttitle, hreflink) {
  return `<a href='` + hreflink + `'>`
    + posttitle.replace(/(^|\s)#([-.\w]+)/gi, `$1</a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"$2"'>#$2</a><a href='` + hreflink + `'>`)
    + '</a>';
}

console.log(formattedTitle('This is #awesome news', 'google.com'));
```

Comment: Didn't realize it would be so simple! Thank you, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the hash symbol out of your capture group; doing so will not change the matching semantics. Like so:

```
function formattedTitle(posttitle, hreflink) {
  return `<a href='`+ hreflink +`'>` + posttitle.replace(/(^|\s)#([-.\w]+)/gi, `$1</a><a class="hashtag" href='/search?q=hashtag:"$2"'>$2</a><a href='`+ hreflink + `'>`) + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another capturing group so that you get a match with the hashtag (or any other character you'd like to capture) in `$2` and another match without the hashtag in `$3`: `(#([-.\w]+))` rather than `(#[-.\w]+)`:

```js
function formattedTitle(postTitle, href) {
  const parts = postTitle.replace(
    /(^|\s)(#([-.\w]+))/gi,
    `$1</a><a class="hashtag" href="/search?q=hashtag:$3">$2</a><a href="${ href }">`);
  
  return `<a href="${ href }">${ parts }</a>`;
}

document.getElementById('postTitle').innerHTML = formattedTitle('This is #awesome news', 'https://google.com');
```

```css
h3 {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

a {
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hashtag {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="postTitle"></h3>
```